# rust xor'ing function and passing same vector twice

Tags: rust

I need a basic xor function that can work on vectors of `u8`

After some quick goolging, I found this, which seemed nice and clean:

```
fn xor(a : Vec<u8>, b:Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>{
   let c =  a.iter()
     .zip(b.iter())
     .map(|(&x1, &x2)| x1 ^ x2)
     .collect();

     c
}
```

And then I called the code like this:

```
let v1: Vec<u8> = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
let v2: Vec<u8> = vec![5, 6, 7, 8];

let v3 = xor(v1, v2);
```

But, I then wanted to test the basic xor property that:

```
 c = xor(a,b)
 a = xor(c,b)
```

I try to do this:

```
let v1: Vec<u8> = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
let v2: Vec<u8> = vec![5, 6, 7, 8];

let v3 = xor(v1, v2);

let v1_ = xor(v1,v3);
```

Which of course complains that `v1` is a moved value.
I then try to use borrowing and passing like `&v1`. which doesn't work.

I try a bunch of other things, like `clone()` which is not defined for vectors.

I see that the docs for vec has a function called `clone` but I can't seem to use it:

```
[src]
impl<T, A> Clone for Vec<T, A>
where
    T: Clone,
    A: Allocator + Clone,
```

But how would I actually do this? how do I use this value again?

Comment: "`clone()` which is not defined for vectors" - could you share an example error? It is definitely defined for `Vec<T>` wherever `T: Clone` (and `u8` is `Clone`, since it's `Copy`), as you've found yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function parameter as references:

```
fn xor(a : &Vec<u8>, b: &Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>{
   let c =  a.iter()
     .zip(b.iter())
     .map(|(&x1, &x2)| x1 ^ x2)
     .collect();

     c
}
```

And then you can pass borrowed values to it:

```
let v3 = xor(&v1, &v2);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=302ef9af1fc415819a4bdba5e845e2b3).

If you are not planning to mutate the vectors, `&[u8]` is preferred over `&Vec<u8>` as commented by @SilvioMayolo:

```
fn xor(a : &[u8], b: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8>
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f3f8ec7549945456c2422d9d87b0e2c1)

Comment: Good answer, but immutable references to `Vec` are [discouraged](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#ptr_arg). Should probably take `&[u8]` arguments instead.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Cool, makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: `&Vec` doesn't allow mutation either. Generally, `&[T]` and `&mut Vec<T>` are reasonable but `&Vec<T>` is _almost never more useful._